# For Loop Constructs

Tags: c#, c++

Will this loop execute exactly `N` Times?

```js
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
{
    //statement
    someMethodCall();
}
```

Will this loop execute at most `N` Times?

```js
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)  
{
    someMethodCall();
}
```

Will this loop execute at least `N` Times?

```js
for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) 
{
    //statement
    someMethodCall();
}
```

What should I do if I need to execute the statement between `m` and `n` times, e.g. calling a method?

Comment: What's with the "at least" or "at most"? A for loop is designed to go through a specific number of times when in that format. A `break` inside the loop would exit early, and formatting it differently would have various effects on the iterations (like going through a container).

Comment: Perhaps.  In all cases, it depends on whether `someMethodCall()` might modify `N`.

Answer (score 2):

The answers to your three questions are yes, no, and yes, I suppose, although that third answer is a bit deceptive; it'll execute N times, no more and no less (unless there's an exception which terminates the loop abnormally.) You can write a for loop to loop a definite number of times, or until some condition becomes true, and then you have the ability to use `break` or `return` to terminate the loop early.

But there's no notion of executing "at least N times;" it's simply not part of this -- or any other -- computer language.

Comment: Well, there's no doubt as to how many times the loop will execute, but I think all three statements are true if you ignore the horrible use of 'at least' and 'at most'.

Comment: @SethCarnegie -- the middle one will execute N-1 times, though, so "at most N" is definitely wrong, wouldn't you say?

Comment: At most really is the only one that can apply if you look at `break` possibilities, but yeah that would be more accurate as "at most, N-1" than "at most, N"

Comment: No, 'at most N' seems correct. It will not run more than N. (And yeah, 'at most' implies some non-determinism which is stupid.)

Comment: @SethCarnegie, it shouldn't run N times though.

Comment: @chris: `at most` doesn't mean it has to run N times, it could run 0 times and the statement is true.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, so saying "at most, N" implies it *can* run N times, whereas "at most, N-1" keeps it clear that it will run N-1 times max. I said "more accurate" before, as technically "at most, N" is still correct, just not the most correct.

Comment: @chris it feels more like 'at most' is setting a ceiling. So I could say "It will run at most N*99999" and be correct. It's like Big-O notation. EDIT: Yes, it is more accurate to say N-1 but, as you said, not incorrect to say the other.

Comment: This is an interesting debate, folks, but I honestly think the poster had some odd delusion about nondeterminism in loop limits, and I think that dispelling these misconceptions is the most important thing here.

Comment: @SethCarnegie `at most N times` means that `N times` is possible, so the statement is incorrect.

Comment: @juanchopanza `define at most` in google says "not more than". So "not more than N" is correct. "Not even N" is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

A loop formula can be calculated as

```
Math.Round (condition - initialization )/increment
```

In first case its

```
(N-0)/1 which evaluates to N times
```

In second case its

```
(N-1)/1 which evaluates to N-1 times
```

In third case its

```
(N-0+1)/1 which evaluates to N+1 times
```

`How would I do if I need to execute statement between m and n times? For instance I want to call one method between m and n times?`

then check it in condition

```
for (int i = m; i < n; i++)
{
    someMethodCall();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In for loop you can have these code,

N Time

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

}
```

N+1 Time

```
for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {

}
```

And if there isn't any time and you want handle it your self you can use this,

```
for (;;) {
   //do something and don't forget use break or return !         
}
```

OR

```
while(x>10){    

}
```

and loop in loop is good as Ernest Friedman-Hill said

```
for (int i = 0; i <=10; i++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    }
}
```

use 2xTab for visual studio help.